# Find matrix of projection and prove direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{R}_n[X]$ be a space of polynomials of degree $\le n$ and coefficient from $\mathbb{R}$

consider subspaces:

$V_1= \{f \in \mathbb{R}_n[X]: \forall a\in \mathbb{R} \ \ f(a)=f(-a) \}$

$V_2= \{f \in \mathbb{R}_n[X]: \forall a\in \mathbb{R} \ \ f(a)=-f(-a) \}$

show that $\mathbb{R}_n[X]=V_1 \oplus V_2$ and find matrix of projection on $V_1$ along $V_2$ at basis $1,x,x^2,...,x^n$

I know $V_1$ are even polynomial and $V_2$ are odd polynomial so it will suggest that $V_1 \cap V_2= \{0\}$ and I think we can obtain any polynomial by adding some from $V_1$ and some from $V_2$ so we then have $V=V_1+V_2$ but I don't know how to solve part with matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis of $V$ is given: $1,x,x^2,\dots, x^n$. Now $1,x^2,\dots$ make up a basis of $V_1$, while $x,x^3,\dots $is a basis of $V_2$.

Now the projection onto $V_1$ along $V_2$ is a splitting of a polynomial $p$ into an even and an odd polynomial.

You have to specify the projection only for the elements in the basis of $V$:
$P(x^{2k})=x^{2k}$, $P(x^{2k+1}) = 0$. Then the matrix representation of this mapping is a diagonal matrix with 1 at odd rows, 0 at even rows.